# Why isn't my question about Nvidia driver dependency issues accepted by Stack Overflow guidelines?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

I'm having trouble understanding why [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319851/nvidia-driver-dependency-issues-for-ubuntu-18-04) does not meet guidelines ("This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in ..."). I asked for help on Nvidia driver dependency problems. I explained the commands that I used to try to solve my problem, and the errors I got. I don't get it. I couldn't find any appropriate tags to use to ask this type of question on this site.

Comment: Quick easy test that works for the majority of questions - what programming language is your question about?

Comment: Because it’s not a programming question—it’s system administration.

Comment: In your own words, in how far is "nvidia driver dependency problems" actually "about programming"?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if when you post on a more appropriate community, the first thing you're to do is update the OS; 18.04 has *very* limited support and in about to entirely run out of support.

Comment: "I couldn't find any appropriate tags to use to ask this type of question on this site." - **that should have been the warning** that the question is off topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I can't tell if you're just trying to install the NVidia driver as a normal end-user of a Linux laptop or if you're trying to install the CUDA variant which would let you do extra compute.

In both cases, it's not the case that a *programmer* would have the expectation to know something about this.  Might be better suited to ask on Unix & Linux.